Sorting algorithm updating a variable that it's not supposed to
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int get_index(char c);
string selectionSort(string arr, int n);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string key = argv[1];
    int str_len = strlen(key);
    string sorted = selectionSort(key, str_len);
}

string selectionSort(string arr, int n)
{

    int i, j, min_idx;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        min_idx = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
            {
                min_idx = j;
            }
        }
        char x = arr[min_idx];
        arr[min_idx] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = x;
    }
    return (string) arr;
}

I've got this c code and the selectionSort function is updating the key variable, how could I do it so the key variable remains unchanged?
I've tried to make a copy of the key but it also gets changed even if I set it to a const.

string is a typedef for a pointer. It doesn't contain any data, it just points to it. If you want to make a copy of that data you can't just copy the pointer, you need to allocate space and copy the contents into that space. An easy way to do this is to use the strdup function if it is available but remember you need to free that memory when you're finished with it.

When posting code, please make sure you have a [mre] to show us.

As for your problem, if you have gotten to this point I would have assumed that CS50 should have told you about pointers, and what string really is.

Since you removed the cs50.h include the string typedef no longer exists and this code doesn't compile.

Strings
Remember that in C that a string is just an array of char. The <cs50.h> kind of hides this from you with a typedef char * string; And it automatically free()s strings it gives you. While convenient, this is, IMHO, a bit of disservice to your understanding.
If you change all instances of string in your code to char * you will immediately begin to see some places where things might go wrong.
Arrays
Arrays are not first-class citizens in C. If you pass an array to a function it actually gets passed as a pointer to the first element in the array — no copy of the array is ever made. The function then gets to do whatever it wants to your array data.
Naming things with extra variables
It can be useful, in terms of readability, to give a more complex thing a simpler name. Having an alias like this can be useful. But beware, doing so may very well obscure stuff you ought to know.
This happens with char * key = argv[1]. As already noted, you aren’t actually getting a copy of the argv[1] string (array) anywhere, just a pointer to it. (You are getting a copy of the pointer to the first element of the string array pointed to by the argv[1] pointer. Clear as mud, right?)
Likewise, collecting the length of the array in a variable to simply use it in one other spot is kind of superfluous, and makes people such as your future self wonder if the variable has a modified value in it instead of the actual current length of the array.
Thus, eschew value aliases when it does not significantly clarify code. In other words, just use the name of the variable directly instead of an alias.
Selection Sort
Sorting algorithms generally modify their argument lists — they do not typically return a new list.
It is a good idea to assume the same of your selection sort. With what we know — strings are arrays, arrays get passed to functions as a pointer to the elements, no copy of the array is made and the function modifies the argument array — we can see that the sort actually modifies the argv[1][] array!
Prototypes > main > functions == Evil
I have never understood, since even before C was standardized in 1998, why people like to list function prototypes, then main(), then the functions. This is an ancient layout, and one that just invites problems and increases mental strain.
Prefer instead to simply define your functions, in order, and have main() last. This will make your life so much easier.
Local variables at the top of the block
This used to be a requirement, again, anciently. Modern C does not require you to declare variables before any statements in a lexical block.
Prefer instead to declare a variable as close as possible to where it is used. In for statements, for example, declare it in the initialization part. The only reason to move it outside the loop is if it is used after the loop has terminated.
Minor commentary
Some commentary to give a general idea of what code is doing is helpful. You do not need to describe what the code itself says. Just give an overview.
For example, on a recipe for a Peanut Butter and Jelly sandwich, the title will be “Peanut Butter and Jelly Sandwich”. It will not tell you that you need a knife or that spreading the peanut butter causes the peanut butter to be spread on the bread.
A general description helps. Anything more just gets in the way.
Apply the knowledge!
Let’s put it all together:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void selectionSort(char * arr, int n)
{
    // while there are unsorted elements
    for (int i = 0;  i < n - 1;  i++)
    {
        // find the smallest unsorted element
        int min_idx = i;
        for (int j = i + 1;  j < n;  j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
            {
                min_idx = j;
            }
        }
        // swap the smallest unsorted with the first unsorted
        // (making the number of sorted elements one more than before)
        char x = arr[min_idx];
        arr[min_idx] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = x;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // The string to sort is passed as first argument to the program
    if (argc != 2) return 1;

    printf("given:  \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
    selectionSort(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
    printf("sorted: \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);

    return 0;
}


Tada! Your code worked!
It might be worth your time looking that selection sort over to understand how it actually works. Hints:

The i counts the number of sorted-elements in the array.
j simply counts through the unsorted elements of the array.
min_idx is ambiguously named — it is the index of the minimum element value in the unsorted section of the array.

Keep going! It gets easier! Promise!
